# What's the minimal column sums difference?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, sum

Imagine you are given a matrix of positive integer numbers (maximum 25*15, value of number does not exceed 3000000). When you do column sums and pick the smallest and the largest one, the difference between them must be the smallest possible.

You can swap numbers in every row (permute rows), not in column, how many times you want.

How would you solve this task?

I'm not asking for your code but your ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly do you need to find? The permutations of the rows for which this happens, or the smallest difference?

Comment: The smallest difference

Comment: Is this from a programming contest?

Comment: Assuming it is, VtC too broad.

Comment: It is not - it is homework to school. But we can't find algorithm that is fast enough to solve inputs under few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an attempt to solve the problem using Simulated Annealing. Here is a sketch of the plan:

1. Let the distance to optimize the difference between the max and min column sums.
2. Set the goal to be 0 (i.e., try to reach as close as possible to a matrix with no difference between sums)
3. Initialize the problem by calculating the array of sums of all columns to their current value.
4. Let a *neighbor* of the current matrix be the matrix that results from swapping two entries in the same row of the matrix.
5. Represent neighbors by their row index and two swapping column indexes.
6. When accepting a neighbor, do not compute all sums again. Just adjust the array of sums in the columns that have been swapped and by the difference of the swap (which you can deduce from the swapped row index)

Step 6 is essential for the sake of performance (large matrices).

Comment: +1 for something that would definitely be interesting to implement, but I think there should be a better solution - I doubt this would do very well in practice.

Comment: @IVlad the reason being...?

Comment: Because there are a lot of states and you won't be able to explore all or even most of them in reasonable time. So you'll have to cut the search early, meaning it will be likely you won't have reached the best solution. And I'm not sure you can estimate how close to the optimum this will get you.

Comment: But that's precisely the strength of Simulated Annealing! It is known to be exceptionally good to find the (global) optimum by analyzing a tiny fraction of the gigantic space of all possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that this problem without the limits is NP-hard, and exact dynamic programming at scale seems out of the question. I think that my first approach would be large-neighborhood local search: repeatedly choose a random submatrix (rows and columns) small enough to be amenable to brute force and choose the optimal permutations while leaving the rest of the matrix undisturbed.

Comment: The limits suggest a smart brute force or DP approach, probably using the fact that there are fewer columns than rows, so something like `O(rows * 2^num_columns)` would definitely work. I'm hoping there is something better than guess and check... what DP did you have in mind?